# No POST response when using checkbox form in my Django template

Tags: html, forms, checkbox, django-templates

Hey there, I am trying to delete Events as chosen by a by a user using
check boxes to check of which events they want to be deleted.  But for
some reason whenever I call request.POST.get('event_list') Nothing is
received even though boxes are checked and I end up with nothing.
Here is my template and the view that should be deleting the chosen
events.

```
 {% if event_list %}
       {% for event in event_list%}
               {%csrf_token%}
               <input type="checkbox" name="event_list"
id="event{{ forloop.counter }}" />
               <label for="event{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ event.title }}</
label><br />
       {% endfor %}
       <input type = 'submit' value = 'delete checked'>
       </form>
       <p>{{removal}}<p/>    {%comment%} this is what should be
removed{%endcomment%}
       {% if delete_error %}
               <p>{{delete_error}}</p>
           {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def EventDelete(request):
       removal = request.POST.get('event_list')
       if removal:
               removal.delete()
       else:
               delete_error = "You didn't delete anything"
       return redner_to_response("detail.html", {'delete_error':
delete_error, 'removal': removal},
context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Im not sure why removal doesn't have anything in it, shouldn't it have
the titles of the events in it?  Unfortunately I don't know much about html and its workings :(  I would really appreciate the help :)  I feel like it is a simple fix and im just missing a small detail.  Thanks :)

Comment: redner_to_response should be render_to_response

Answer (score 0):

The checkboxes have no value so you'll just get "on" sent to the server.

This:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="event_list"
 id="event{{ forloop.counter }}" />
```

should read

```
<input type="checkbox" name="event_list"
 id="event{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ forloop.counter }}" />
```

And then (once the server has received a list of ids), your code for processing it looks wrong, you need to somehow load the list of ids, and work out what to delete. You probably want something like

```
removal = request.POST.get('event_list')
for id in removal:
     event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=id)
     event.delete()
```

I think you have a fair bit to learn! Check out [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for monitoring what is actually being sent back to your server. Go to [w3schools to learn about forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), and read the django documentation for handling the deletion.