# Django - Iterating Checkboxes from ManyToManyField then adding in Views

Tags: django, checkbox

I'm making a program to let users create lists out of all of the contacts they have available. I'd like to have the entire list iterate with checkboxes, then in the views, add all the checked boxes to the Contact List's contacts list in one go.

I know how to iterate the checkboxes, but I don't know how to tell the views to check all the boxes to see which ones are checked, then add the associated user to the list.

In models.py:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='organizations')

class Contact(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

class ContactList(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name='contact_lists')
```

In contactlist.html:

```
<form action="/contactlists/add_contacts/ method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for contact in contacts %}
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" value="{{contact.unique_id}}">{{contact.name}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="New Contact List">
```

In views.py:

```
def add_contacts(request, organization_id=1):
    organization = Organization.objects.get(id=organization_id)
    contacts = Contact.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contacts_to_add = request.POST.getlist('contacts')
        for contact in contacts_to_add:
            if contact.contacts:
                contact = Contact.objects.filter(unique_id=contact.unique_id)[0]
                contactlist.contacts.add(contact)
    args = {'contacts': contacts, 'organization': organization}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'contactlist.html', args)
```

Comment: You should be able to work off of this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19949097/1637351

Comment: Sorry, it's not helpful :/ I've been looking at it for days now and I don't see how it's relevant to what I'm trying to do

Comment: Actually this link was the one that did it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893462/no-post-response-when-using-checkbox-form-in-my-django-template